# Does Apple Watch ever contribute to significant location/visit monitoring?

Tags: ios, watchkit, core-location, apple-watch

Say an app asks Core Location for low-power background updates - e.g. significant location changes via [`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati) or CLVisits via [`startMonitoringVisits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1618692-startmonitoringvisits). The user has an Apple Watch with GPS. They then leave their iPhone at home for a while, and wear their watch.

Are there any circumstances under which Core Location will use the watch's location and movement, rather than the phone, for background location monitoring? For example, if the user goes to the store wearing their watch, and then returns home, iOS would automatically use the watch's location to eventually deliver location/visit events to the iOS app showing that the user left the house.

I suspect that iOS does not have this capability, for a variety of reasons. But I haven't found any documentation that addresses this explicitly. I work on an app that implements CLVisit monitoring, and looking at the CLVisit events delivered to the app, I *believe* that watch location data is never used in this way, but haven't really proved it. So I'd like to see if someone has a definitive answer on this.

Note I'm not talking about workout sessions that can use the watch GPS, just the more passive, low-power location monitoring options provided by CLLocationManager — none of which appear to be directly available to watchOS apps, thus my research into whether iPhone apps can at least take advantage of watch location data for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app runs on the iPhone, using Core Location, it uses the iPhone location hardware (GPS/WiFi/cell).  When your app runs on the Watch, it uses the Watch's location hardware.  iOS is not going to pull location data from the device that you are *not* running on, only from the device where the app is running.

I suppose you could write both a phone and watch app and they could exchange location data with each other.